# How to fade/blend between 2 divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="#content1">
    <div id="divWelcome" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div id="headerimg" style="position: relative;">
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom:255px; left: 20px; width: 550px; font-family:DIN; font-size:23pt; font-weight:600; color: white; letter-spacing:0.01em;">
                We offer Cloud solutions for small businesses to help them manage their workflow requirements
            </div>

            <hr style="height:6px;position: absolute; bottom:210px; left: 20px; width: 490px;"/>


            <div style="position: absolute; bottom:175px; left: 20px; width: 550px; font-family:DIN; font-size:14pt; font-weight:500; color: white; letter-spacing:0.01em;">
               Our core sectors of expertise are professional services, data management and outsourcing.
            </div>

        </div>


        <div id="divAboutContents" style="margin-top:50px; background-color:red;position: relative;display: none;">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So when the page loads the 1st div shows. The effect I want is when the user presses a button the `divFirst` gently fades away and the `divSecond` gently fades in. I have used this bit of jQuery but the affect does not look very pleasing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divAbout").click(function () {
            $("#headerimg").fadeOut();
            $("#divAboutContents").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

What else can I try/read up on? Thanks

NB
This is part of my CSS

```
#content1 {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also I was fading the other one out. just forgot to put it in the question. The affect I get is 'clunky'

Comment: Please define "not very pleasing"? What is actually happening? It is because the fade starts while content is visible or just not smooth?

Comment: this is not a duplicate. I had posted that other question and it did not work for me so I re-posted it the fuller html. Please reopen

Comment: Pauline - please check the facts,  The previous answer did NOT answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap the 2 divs in position:relative div and set them to absolute positioning. This way the divs will be one over the other and you don't have to fade out the bottom div, just fade in/out the top div and it will create the fade effect.

Comment: sounds promising. This is all new to me. Could you provide a fuller answer please? thanks

Comment: They *already are* absolutely positioned in a relative positioned div (inline styles).